# An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, build, ionic3

I am a newbie to Ionic 3. I have done an application and tried to convert to apk.

I am generating debug (or testing) android-debug.apk using below CLI :

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

Page declares in  declarations and entryComponents.

This is my **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    LoginPage,
    MobileScreenPage,
    OtpScreenPage,
    RegisterPage,
    ForgotPasswordPage,
    EditProfilePage,
    MemberDetailPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    LoginPage,
    MobileScreenPage,
    OtpScreenPage,
    RegisterPage,
    ForgotPasswordPage,
    EditProfilePage,
    MemberDetailPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    AuthServiceProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: You edit profile page is part of 2 modules. Remove it from App Module and it will work,

Comment: If I remove it from app.module.ts it shows error  `Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting same component in multiple ngModule array. Try to add this in upper level module.

If you want to use same component in multiple modules try to make it a separate module and export that component in that module

your.module.ts

```
 declarations: [
        YourComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
    ],
    exports: [YourComponent]
```

**Edit: 1**

You can not register one component in multiple modules. If you want same component in multiple different modules. Try to make make that component a separate module and import that module where ever you want. In your case, remove EditProfilePage from app module's declarations and add this line in your EditProfilePageModule.

**EditProfilePageModule.ts**

```
exports: [EditProfilePage]
```

Now in your app.module.ts import the EditProfilePage module

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
        CommonModule,
        EditProfilePageModule,
    ],
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Can you explain it?

Comment: Does this help to fix your problem?

Comment: Ii works. but now I am stuck in another issue. if you can help me with that. I am running it on the web and it works perfectly after login move to the Home page.  But on a device after login it will navigate to the next page but on back press it will navigate to agin login. I want to finish the activity. Means remove the previous page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205434/discussion-between-ali-wahab-and-unnati-patadia).